# RxKotlin zip inside flatmap

Tags: android, reactivex, rx-kotlin

This is my code template

```
getLastMessageSingle()
.flatmap(
    message->
    if(message.image==null)
        Single.Just(message)
    else
        Single.zip(t1,t2,BiFunction<String,String,String>{
            s1,s2->
          //body sets data to message

          message
        })
)
//subscribe part
```

I found that Single.Just will execute but zip part is never executed. Am i doing any thing wrong or flat function does not support zip in it.

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Solution:

It was my mistake second single t2 did not produce a response.

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint and debug it? It’s not clear what you’re trying to do here.

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes and BiFunction is never gets called.

Comment: The code you posted is not "complete" as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and i didn't understand the reason.
The strange part is that when you use zip, only the last line which return a value is called!!! All the lines before that will not execute.

So i make a model and fill it with the responses and return it in last line and do all the logic part in my subscribe.

Answer (score 0):

Your two functions must give some response for zip to be produce a response.